# Firebase syncing contacts with server

Tags: android, firebase

I am using Firebase as backend server/db. I wish to sync the users phone contacts with the server as in, checking the users phone numbers against all users present within the app, looking for matches.

The schema I have is:

```
{
  "presentUsersByPhoneNumber" : {
    "1614#######" : "54977412-ee62-443a-bbc8-c908c1d65f23",
    "1614#######" : "fdb17f3a-7b7d-4aa5-9a0b-b9fb33c349de",
    "1614#######" : "afa934ee-ee84-40e7-96c5-0a66429b5fb0",
    "1614#######" : "99e4989b-a046-4c5f-9478-5ebd8bdc3ded",
    "1614#######" : "1783917f-00e4-47a0-b2cd-987bdf185129",
    "1614#######" : "a96da7b1-7c4e-44bc-b82e-fc75bed52bcd"
  },
```

At present, the only method of doing so, appears to be to download all the users within the database, and subsequently compare, given a `.removeAll` from a tree set, to the present users contact numbers.

This way appears highly inefficient and would waste much data.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: That depends on what you currently do. Don't describe your code, show your code.

Comment: In firebase I know is possible to search for one key very quickly.  But I need to search for potentially hundreds of keys,  given a list of phone numbers,  and only return the matches.

Comment: And you already seem to know that's not possible. So why are we here?

Comment: The most efficient way to accomplish what I just described

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, in that case, would I have to send potentially hundreds of independent requests, one for each of the uses contacts phone number, to check if a user already has been created with that phone number?